# onOptionsItemSelected not starting intent

Tags: android, android-intent

So here's the rundown: I have an activity with an options menu. There is only 1 options in the list which is: "Options" 
The Problem: When I click on the Options item, it kicks me back to the previous screen. I put in a toast to display just randomness so I know it's reading the id, it's just not doing to Intent?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_screen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        Intent Options = new Intent(this,
                Options.class);
        this.startActivity(Options);
        Toast msg = Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this,
                "Just some text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        msg.show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Xml:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
    android:title="Sell"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
```

It just **wont** take me to the options screen... 
No error message or anything.

Comment: In onCreate of the Options class just log it to see if it is called.

Comment: post the onCreate code for this class. Also log onResume, onPause, onStop and onDestroy

Comment: Ok I guess it's not calling the Class at all